# If a basis for $V$ intersects an $m$-dimensional subspace of $V$ at $m$ basis vectors, will these $m$ vectors form a basis for the subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, hamel-basis, linear-independence

Sorry, I might be asking a stupid question, but somehow I can't convince myself of the assertion in the title:

Let $\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ be a basis for a vector space $(V,F)$ and suppose $S$ is an $m$-dimensional subspace of $V$. Now, if the first $m$ vectors in the basis happen to be elements of $S$, can we conclude that they form a basis for $S$?

My guess is a yes, and I would justify it by showing these $m$ vectors are linearly independent in $S$. Suppose the contrary. Then there exist not-all-zero scalars $a_1,\ldots,a_m\in F$ such that
$$a_1 u_1+\cdots+a_m u_m=\mathbf{0},$$
but the expression
$$a_1 u_1+\cdots+a_m u_m+0 u_{m+1}+\cdots+0 u_n=\mathbf{0}$$
will imply linear dependence of $\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ in $V$, violating the fact that it is a basis for $V$.

Does my reasoning work? Thank you.

Comment: Your reasoning and conclusion are correct. Linear dependency/independency does not depend on the ambient space.

Comment: As @AnneBauval asserted, your reasoning is correct. Which part of your reasoning do you find doubtful or have less confidence in? We can help you with that if you wish.

Comment: Since you edited your post, it is still correct except the title. The hypothesis $\dim S=m$ is necessary.

Comment: @AnneBauval Is there anything I can improve in the title? Thank you.

Comment: Add that hypothesis (and specify $m$ as the number of those "intersected vectors", or rollback to your first version, at least in the title.

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh, thank you. I guess I know what you mean, but I'm thinking how to edit the title to meet the requirement for the length of a title.